# Wrong text position in Textview Landscape mode, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, landscape, gravity

I have this Landscape Activity (she can't switch in Portrait mode):

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
```

I see the Android Studio preview with correct text vertical position:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2qltjmf.jpg

but when i running the app on my Moto G 2013 i see this:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/milwf7.jpg

I already tried: layout_centerVertical="true", gravity="center_vertical" and all layout command. Now i think the problem is other: the top part of layout is cut off the screen. Any can help me? Ty

Comment: Is that your full xml layout?

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I copied the entire xml in "blockcode" but it appears only textview layout. As soon  as i go back home i will post the entire code, but it's a simple lineare layout

Comment: the complete code is it:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/wvcx8y.jpg

Comment: your xml file seems fine, are you doing any changes to textview in your activity ?

Comment: You need use gravity ="center" in text view :) have fun

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I finded the solution. Although i tried the post well-formed, my ask was failed. The error was in subclass, where I set a old Typeface font, applied a this textbox.